# Lists getListItems method

Tags: list, web-services

I am invoking the Lists web service in Sharepoint 2010 and need to retrieve a single list Item only. I have the URL to the actual item and I am framing my query like this:

```
`<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
 <S:Body>
<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><listName>{5cbc4407-3851-4e00-964a-bb7e9b430f9f}</listName>    <viewName></viewName>    <rowLimit>1000</rowLimit>    <webID></webID>
<Query>
<Where>
<And>
<Eq>
**<FieldRef Name = "EncodedAbsUrl" >
</FieldRef><Value Type = "Text">http://sp10/Shared Documents/Ashish/Word_feb27.doc</Value></Eq>**
</And>
</Where>
</Query>
<viewFields>
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="FSObjType"/><FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/><FieldRef Name="UniqueId"/><FieldRef Name="FileRef"/>
<FieldRef Name="FileRef"/><FieldRef Name="EncodedAbsUrl"/><FieldRef Name="FileSizeDisplay"/><FieldRef Name="_UIVersionString"/>

<FieldRef Name="_owshiddenversion"/>
</ViewFields>
</viewFields>
</GetListItems>    
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

However the results that I get are multiple where it really should be just retrieving one z:row.

Anybody know what's up?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is invalid because of the *And* element.  It is throwing off your query and returning all the rows. This will result in all the rows being returned. Either add a second condition or remove the element.

Comment: yep, I just altered that....but it is still returning all the elements, apparently it did not make a difference :P

Comment: You will often see "extra" rows coming back when the CAML query syntax in invalid.  PirateEric's suggestion to use a tool to compose the query is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Can try debugging the CAML in BIWUG CAMLDesigner, http://sharepoint.biwug.be/CamlDesigner/CamlDesigner.application